# Редирект https сайта

Tags: .htaccess

В файл `.htaccess` сделал следующие

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Он перенаправляет все страницы  типа example.com/newdir/

Но example.com/index.html или example.com/1.png  Остаются на http соединение.

Как сделать полный редирект на https?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть как *проблему, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечатку*, потому что вопрошающий [не туда прописывал настройки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635642/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-https-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0#comment898589_635643).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный сниппет для такого редиректа:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Ещё вариант(с ENV):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

*Главное, не добавлять других `RewriteCond`, про существование файлов и т.п.*

---

Другой путь(вероятно более правильный) - прописать редирект прямо в настройках VirtualHost:

```
<virtualhost *:80="">
  ServerName www.example.com
  Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</virtualhost>
```

Comment: Вообще работоспособность `%{HTTPS}=off` зависит от конкретного сервера, у меня иногда не работало и приходилось другие условия прописывать (правда, уже хз какие)

Comment: `<virtualhost *:8080>
  ServerName example.com 
 ServerAlias www.example.com 
  Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</virtualhost>`
Сделал так и не работает

Comment: Без редиректа https же работает?

Comment: https работает если руками перейти на него. Мне надо чтоб если человек перешел http://example.com/index.html его перекинуло на https://example.com/index.html

Comment: Ну, так и должно работать. Только что проверил у себя, работает

Comment: Вы же не в .htaccess этот virtualhost прописываете?

Comment: Так мне надо на автомате чтобы перекидывала. virtualhost я в apache  прописываю

Comment: Был включен nginx. Прописал для него изменения и все заработало